# Keeping Fragments Broadcast Receivers active even when not in view

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity with two fragments, with only 1 of the two fragments being displayed at a given time, as determined by the user. Both fragments subscribe to data via a broadcast receiver.

The acitivty manages which fragment is displayed using the fragment manager's replace() method, e.g.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.north_fragment, fragment1, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
```

The Broadcast Receivers are registered in the Fragment's onCreateView() override: The broadcast receiver receives the appropriate data as expected.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spectrum_analyzer_graph, container, false);

    setupGraphView(rootView);

    // register for Spectrum Frame Response messages
    myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive()");
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

The broadcast receiver is unregistered in onDestroyView(), e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(m_spectrumDataFrameReceiver);
}
```

Is there a way I can keep the fragment receiving data through the BroadcastReceiver, even when it's not visible (after it's been destroyed)? I want the receiver to continue getting data and storing it in the Fragment, even if the fragment is not visible (but the activity is visible), but I know that I need to unregister the broadcast receiver at some point.

Should unregistration be done when the Activity is destroyed (calling in to its activities to unregister), or is it too late here? I'm fairly new to the intricacies of Fragment lifecyle, and am not quite sure what to do.

Comment: You could register the receiver in your Activity since it's always there, send the data to the visible fragment, and hold the data of the one not visible. When you show the second fragment, make it ask the activity for his data.

Comment: That seems to add a lot of coupling. I feel like a fragment should avoid knowing specifics of the Activity it's attached to, or that it has to get information from it.

Comment: what about registering/unregistering the receiver at onCreate()/onDestroy() and setting setRetainInstance() to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `replacing` each fragment everytime just use the `add` method fragment transaction so it is still alive when invisible.

**solution:**

replace the `replace` use the `add`

```
beginTransaction().add(R.id.north_fragment, fragment1, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
```

Comment: So, if I add a fragment at a location where one is already (R.id.north_fragment), it won't call onDestroyView(), but presumbably some other Fragment lifecycle method(s)? onPause()? onStop() ?

Comment: @StealthRabbi yes it wont destroy cause you are adding it to the top of one fragment,

Comment: I'm getting the following exception when trying to add the fragment thta's already there.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added:

Also, adding the second fragment where the first one currently is, does nothing. Do I need to use show() / hide() ?

Answer (score 1):

You should register your receiver in activity onResume  and unregister it in onPause. You receiver will receive broadcast as long as activity is running. Then you can pass received data to respective fragment by any means.

Comment: Yeah, I've realized that my desire to register receivers in my fragments doesn't scale well, especially if all the fragments register for the same thing. I ultimately went with your suggestion, but I feel that Rod's answer below truly answered what I asked.